# Partial Differential Equations - Characteristic Curves

Tags: derivatives, partial-derivative, characteristic-functions, slope

I am going through a book on partial differential equations, and am slightly confused by this paragraph:

> Consider the equation $\frac{dy}{dx}=p(x, y)$.
>
> a) Think of solutions to this equations as curves in the $xy$ plane. 
>   The equation is telling us that the slop of the tangent line to a
>   solution curve at the point $(x_0, y_0)$ is equal to $p(x_0, y_0)$.
>
> b) We can also say that the solution curve at the point $(x_0, y_0)$
>   is changing in the direction of the vector $(1, p(x_0, y_0))$.

Where does the vector $(1, p(x_0, y_0))$ come from? Is this simply the gradient?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If $m$ is the slope of a tangent line to a curve, then the tangent vector of the curve is parallel to the $(1,m)$ vector in the $(x,y)$-plane.
Think of it as going back to the "rise over run" ($\frac{\Delta y}{\Delta x}$) idea: We move $1$ unit in $x$ and $m$ units in $y$. Here $m= p(x_0,y_0)$.

Comment: Excuse me. I want to know more about this 1 unit (for example, the notion $1$ in the $(1,m)$). Does the 1 unit a unit vector like $(1,0)$ in the plane?

Comment: I'm not sure I understand your question

Comment: Sorry for the misunderstanding. What is the 1 unit? Is it a vector?